# How to build apk using commandline

Tags: android

I Want to build apk using commandline, I am using ant server by using it I am building apk with commandline but when I give this command `ant debug` it shows error BUILD FAILED Unable to locate tools.jar and then it gives error source resource doesnt exist

Comment: hey thanks Bo. For the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because your JAVA_HOME is not set to your C:\Program Files\Java\jdk folder.
instead it might be set to C:\Program Files\Java\jre so it's not getting tools.jar.
just check out this. 
You can do this in this way:

```
C:\>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk
C:\>ant debug
```

You need tools.jar file from your jdk/lib/ folder.

Comment: actually build.xml isnt in my project so how can i get that in my project ?

Comment: verify your android-sdk path... else can u tell what is the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: Actually i dont have build.xml but i have taken from somewhere else and put into my project actually it gives this error "BUILD FAILED Unable to locate tools.jar and then it gives error source resource doesnt exist"

Comment: have you set JAVA_HOME to your jdk folder?

Comment: yes i have set this now whats the next step can u please tell me?

Comment: You are in linux or windows.. If in linux just check our this `echo %JAVA_HOME%` and give it's output..

Comment: Check out [http://forums.devshed.com/java-help-9/ant-unable-to-locate-tools-jar-and-setting-environmental-variables-122244.html](http://forums.devshed.com/java-help-9/ant-unable-to-locate-tools-jar-and-setting-environmental-variables-122244.html)  If your problem gets solved through this..

Comment: try to do this in your ANT_HOME/bin directory. Is it working there?

Comment: oh sorry i was taking lunch , i m using windows

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12529/discussion-between-jay-thakkar-and-user1440140)

Comment: Hello where to keep tools.jar have i to keep in the project ?? i facing this error    ""    files\java\jdk1.6.0_19 was unexpected at this time     ""